# Use assign to create multiple functions inside of a function in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a few functions that do slightly different things and that can each accept a global variable.

I use `assign` to assign the function `this_value` to the name it should have, `this_key`. The three functions it should create are `func_a`, `func_b`, and `func_c`.

Each newly minted function should be able to take an input `x` and do something particular to that function to `x`; in this case, print "key_name: `name` ----- value_x: `x`". So `name` should depend on whether the function is `func_a`, `func_b`, or `func_c`; e.g., calling `func_a` should give us "key_name: a".

```
to_name <- c("a", "b", "c")

create_funcs <- function() {
  all_funcs <- list()

  for (name in to_name) {
    this_key <- paste0("func_", name)

    this_value <<- function(x) { 
      paste0("key_name:  ", name, " -----  value_x: ", x)
    }
    assign(this_key, this_value, envir = .GlobalEnv) 

    all_funcs <- c(all_funcs, this_key)
  }
  return(all_funcs)
}

create_funcs()
```

However, after creating the functions, they each only return a `name` of "c", or the last value in the vector `to_name`.

```
func_a("foo")  # key_name:  c -----  value_x: foo
func_b("bar")  # key_name:  c -----  value_x: bar
```

Instead, `func_a("foo")` should return "key_name:  a -----  value_x: foo".

For what it's worth, this works in a similar object-assigning function:

```
create_objects <- function() {
  all_objs <- list()

  for (name in to_name) {
    this_key <- paste0("key_", name)

    this_value <- paste0("value_", name)

    assign(this_key, this_value, envir = .GlobalEnv)

    all_objs <- c(all_objs, this_key)
  }
  return(all_objs)
}

create_objects()
```

Example:

```
key_a  # value_a
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this solves your problem, since your real use case is probably more complicated than this reproducible example. But you might want to check out [`purrr::partial`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/partial.html).

Here's a possible solution I came up with using that function.

```r
library(purrr)

func_ <- function(x, key_name) {
  paste0("key_name:  ", key_name, " -----  value_x: ", x)
}


func_a <- partial(func_, key_name = "a")

func_a("foo")

#> [1] "key_name:  a -----  value_x: foo"


assign("func_b", partial(func_, key_name = "b"))

func_b("foo")

#> [1] "key_name:  b -----  value_x: foo"
```

**EDIT:**

Here you can just take and character vector and iterate over each element (like with a for loop) using [`purrr::walk`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) to create a new function for each one. You just have to make sure to set the environment to `.GlobalEnv` in the `assign()` call. I don't know that much about environment scoping for things like this, and feel like I've read that this can sometimes be a bad idea, but it seems to do what you described. Hope this helps.

```r
letters %>% walk(~ assign(x = paste0("func_", .x),
                          value = partial(func_, key_name = .x),
                          envir = .GlobalEnv))

func_x("foo")

#> [1] "key_name:  x -----  value_x: foo"
```

Comment: The one thing is I still would like to be able to do the assignment within the for loop so I don't have to name each function individually outside the function. Something like this `all_funcs <- c(all_funcs, partial(func_, name = name, envir = .GlobalEnv))` gives the same result as above (i.e., `func_a("foo")  # key_name:  c -----  value_x: foo`)

Comment: @amanda I've edited the answer to add an example of creating multiple functions like this with a loop. Hope it's helpful

Comment: perfect, thanks a ton. guess I'd better get on the `purrr` train!

Comment: @amanda Glad it was helpful. Yeah, `purrr` is great - in addition to [purrr.tidyverse.org](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/), you might want to check out this [chapter in R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html)

Comment: totally, you've convinced me that the end of this chapter is even more useful than the beginning. fantastic book. if you're interested in how your solution is being put to use you'll find it in `construct_funcs.R` here https://github.com/aedobbyn/beer-data-science. still early stages so nothing much to show yet but hoping to knit some of it together soon!

Comment: That looks like a cool project, thanks for sharing. I'll keep an eye out to see how it goes.