# Modifying functions and their names based on variables in global environment

Tags: r, function, global-variables

Let's say I have a feature dataframe, f

```
f = data.frame(X1 = 1:10,
                X2 = 11:20,
                X3 = 21:30)
```

And an outcome vector, o

```
o = 1:10
```

Is there a way for me to create the following 3 functions based on f's variables -- i.e., glmfun_X1, glmfun_X2, glmfun_X3 -- without writing each one out? e.g., I would rather NOT write out:

```
glmfun_X1 = function(X, Y) {
  glmout = glm(Y ~ ., data = data.frame(X[,"X1"]))
  return(glmout)
}

glmfun_X2 = function(X, Y) {
  glmout = glm(Y ~ ., data = data.frame(X[,"X2"]))
  return(glmout)
}

glmfun_X3 = function(X, Y) {
  glmout = glm(Y ~ ., data = data.frame(X[,"X3"]))
  return(glmout)
}
```

I would need the functions to be stored in my global environment, so that the following works:

```
glmfun_X1(X = f, Y = o)
glmfun_X2(X = f, Y = o)
glmfun_X3(X = f, Y = o)
```

I tried something using a combination of: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223711/use-assign-to-create-multiple-functions-inside-of-a-function-in-r) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100415/modify-function-in-global-environment)

```
glmfun <- function(X, Y) {
  glmout = glm(Y ~ ., data = data.frame(X[,xname]))
  return(glmout)
}


for (i in colnames(f)) {
  assign(x = paste0("glmfun_", i),
         value = glmfun,
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
  body(paste0("glmfun_", i))[[2]][[3]][[3]][[2]][[4]] = i
}

glmfun_X1(X = f, Y = o)
glmfun_X2(X = f, Y = o)
glmfun_X3(X = f, Y = o)
```

However, this doesn't work because `xname` isn't able to be changed within each function to `"X1"`, `"X2"`, and `"X3"`, respectively, using the `body` function and a for-loop (I tried lapply, as well, but thought a for-loop would provide a clearer illustration. I got the same error using lapply). Note that, individually, this does work:

```
i = "X1"
body(glmfun_X1)[[2]][[3]][[3]][[2]][[4]] = i # this works
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: and why would you create a static function? You should consider running the models and storing the objects in a list. No need of the functions

Comment: I need to have the static functions to pass into an ensemble learner

Comment: You do not need static functions. You need one function. Ensure to pass the correct arguments into the function

Comment: purr:walk could be used to create partials

Comment: @user12256545 might you be able to show me what you mean? I tried using purr:walk, but from what I understand that can modify what's being passed into the function, not the function itself (i.e., the body of the function)...but I may be mistaken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to use a for-loop and a eval-parse routine.

```
f = data.frame(X1 = 1:10,
               X2 = 11:20,
               X3 = 21:30)


for (i in names(f)) {
  eval(parse(text=paste0("glmfun_",i,"<-function(X, Y) {glm(Y ~ .,data=data.frame(X[,'",i,"']))}")))
}
```

i removed the return statement to make it more concise.